# SVG clip-path to create a "handdrawn" div - compatibility issues and alternatives?

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I want to recreate a "hand-drawn/brushstroke" style div on a white background, like in this image:

[image]

It seemed like the perfect match for the `clip-path`-CSS styling. I went ahead and created an SVG, used the `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` attribute and encountered the first problem. When using `clip-path: url(urlto.svg#pathid);` it did not render, but when I included the SVG on the page (hidden), it worked. I have read this multiple times on StackOverflow but never read any solution to this. Is that behaviour normal?

As said, I got it to work with the site-embedded SVG, but as seen on the spec-documentation of the `clip-path` functionality, WebKit (Safari and iOS in general) has its problems rendering the thing correctly. I tried prefixing, but that didn't work either.

My question would be: Do you think there is a possibility that I might have missed something in the SVG or in the CSS-Specification that might make it work in Safari? Or, if not, do you think that the problem can be resolved using the `mask-border`attribute? Does that make a difference rendering-wise? I did not manage to find the current setup to make this work - basically, as I understood it, I would need to include the same SVG and "slice" it (9-field) correctly. However, I don't understand where that border is added as I would need it to be "inwards" of the div.

I hope this makes somehow sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you may be able to use a `mask` instead, although that comes with its own set of [compatibility issues](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks). - Maybe you should explain why you cannot use an inline definition for the clip-path

Comment: An alternative to reach the same effect, as your background is intended to be white, would be to just absolute position the svg over the image and hence reduce all compatibility issues down to the bare use of svg I think. clip-path seems like overdoing it unless you want to achieve transparency towards a background image or such.

Comment: @ccprog : Thank you for commenting! Do you know if the rendering-problems between `clip-path` and `mask-border` are inherently linked (as in "if the one doesn't work then the other one won't either")? the inline-definition-problem is just something that was bugging me and I was asking myself if maybe I was missing some important attributes in the SVG that could be linked with the rendering problem...

Comment: @TimLind : A very good suggestion indeed... I might try this out - it would work for every single-color background.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can do it using CSS & blend-modes if this is suitable for you:

```css
div{position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;}
div img{position:absolute;
}
img:nth-of-type(2){mix-blend-mode: screen;}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" alt="Darwin" />
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/brush.gif" alt="brush" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! I was not aware of blend-modes and will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I ended up using probably the simplest method for my use-case, as suggested by the user Timlind - thanks again for your comment!

```
<div id="container">
   # CONTENT #
  <div id="cover"><img src="path/to/svg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is straightforward:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

watch out for the `viewbox` definition inside the SVG to facilitate scaling (no fixed with and height in the svg-definition) and set `preserveAspectRatio="none"` (for this use-case).

`pointer-events: none` allows users to "click through" the svg-overlay.